# Showying $f(x+iy) = x^2+iy^3$ isn't analytic in an open set of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

I need to show that:

$$f(x+iy) = x^2+iy^3$$

isn't analytic on an open set of $\mathbb{C}$, i.e., the set of points where it's differentiable isn't an open set. Here's what I did:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2x$$
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 3y^2$$

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \implies 2x = 3y^2 $$

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0$$

As you can see, by the Cauchy Riemann equations, the second one is always valid, but the first one is always valid when $3y^2 = 2x$. So if the funciton is differentiable, then it must be on the set of points $3y^2=2x$, because the partials are continuous everywhere. Can I argue that this set of points is a parabola and thus a 'line' which is a closed set of $\mathbb{C}$?

Am I right?

Comment: Does the set of points on the parabola constitute an open set in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Dr.MV I think they don't

Comment: Then, you have your answer.

Comment: Since you seem unsure about the open set part, you should write it out carefully yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I would agree with your conclusion a complex function $f(z)$ is holomorphic if the Cauchy-Riemann equations are both satisfied .From your problem the only path over which they are both satisfied is $3y^2=2x$. I don't see a problem with your conclusion. However it is not an open set.

Comment: The problem is that the set of points on the parabola is not an open one.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is analytic$\implies$both $u$ and $v$ are harmonic in $x$ and $y$.
Now, think the contrapositive of the above statement.

Comment: but am I wrong?

Comment: Inspite of saying, it is closed, you must state that the parabola $3y^2=2x$ is not open in $\mathbb C$.